# Location of the persistence.xml in a Java Client App

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence.xml

I am a newbie in Hibernate. In order to get the transaction by the EntityManager, I need to use EntityManager Factory. When I put this code block on my file:

```
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence
            .createEntityManagerFactory("Comment");

EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();

transaction.begin();
entityManager.persist(obj);
transaction.commit();
```

I got this Exception:

**javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named Comment**

Then I realized that I need to add a persistence.xml file:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemalocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">
  <persistence-unit name="QuestionsComments" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>Comment</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="root"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sogdb"/>
      <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Actually, The app I am using is not a Java on Server app (I have a Client app). Which means that there is no META-INF folder that will contain the persistence.xml file.

My Questions are:

1- Where I need to put the persistence.xml file?

2- Is the code below OK? Knowing that my table in the database is **QuestionsComments** and my class that will be related to it using Hibernate is **Comment**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Eclipse, adding the JPA facet to your project allows Eclipse to take care of setting these things up for you.  It will create the META-INF folder, and can generate a stub persistence.xml file in it. You don't have to be running the code on a server to have a META-INF folder in your jar file.

When you are creating the [EntityManagerFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Persistence.html#createEntityManagerFactory%28java.lang.String%29) the string argument should be the name of the persistence unit.  I'd recommend using annotations in your entity class for specifying table name, id column, etc.

Edit: fixed link.

Answer (score 0):

1. Answered clearly in this section of the [Hibernate JPA Quick Start Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/quickstart/en-US/html/ch04.html). It goes in `META-INF`.
2. Check out the same guide just linked.

Personally I prefer the Hibernate-specific configuration `hibernate.cfg.xml` with annotations for mappings and Hibernate's `SessionFactory` for transaction access; I find it easier to wrap my head around -- although that's probably because I originally learned how to use Hibernate without knowing how to use JPA.